# Mongoose find by ref ObjectId not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

[Mongoose] Find by Ref ObjectId not working properly

I want to find teams by ref ObjectId but unable to find

My team model

```
const teamSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  territoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Territory' },
  deleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

teamSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  this.updated_at = currentDate;
  if (!this.created_at) this.created_at = currentDate;
  next();
});

const team = mongoose.model('team', teamSchema);

module.exports = team;
```

search.js

```
      const teams = await Team.find({
        territoryId: requiredTerritory._id,
      });
```

It is working fine when I'm using mongodbCompass but when I try in code it only give 2 out of 9 results

[MongoDBCompass find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRSE8.png)
[Search.js find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSmPA.png)

Comment: Where is this `requiredTerritory._id` come from? show the full code..